# What's the maximum pid for Mac OS X?

Tags: kernel

The Mac OS X Internals book [states](http://books.google.com/books?id=K8vUkpOXhN4C&pg=PA752&lpg=PA752&dq=pid_max%20mac%20os%20x&source=bl&ots=OKklWYWyUu&sig=Lle5nUNwHj2KAciO3rGFpy_Vk0c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zG2tT9q6FaS36QHs3-DqDA&ved=0CIEBEOgBMAc#v=onepage&q&f=false) that the maximum [process identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) is 30,000 and after that the kernel will start re-using pids.  But checking on my own system, via:

`ps a | grep ps | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`

I can see that I have pids that go higher.  Does anyone know if there is a pid_max explicitly set somewhere, like in Linux?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at [sys/proc_internal.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.24.23/bsd/sys/proc_internal.h) in xnu-1699.24.23, I find that PID_MAX is 99999.  The value is used in [kern_fork.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.24.23/bsd/kern/kern_fork.c) in the function `forkproc`.  Looking at that function, process IDs are not assigned equal to PID_MAX, so the highest possible pid is 99998.

Comment: The book is out of date, it did use to be 30000 (xnu-792 - Tiger) and changed to 99999 when xnu-1228 was released (Leopard)

Comment: [macOS Catalina uses xnu-6153](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina#Release_history). Links for the code in the answer: [sys/proc_internal.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-6153.141.1/bsd/sys/proc_internal.h.auto.html); [kern_fork](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-6153.141.1/bsd/kern/kern_fork.c.auto.html). Kyle's answer appears still to be correct in this version.

Comment: Note also, looking at `forkproc`, that it appears PIDs must be positive.

Comment: *Except the kernel task, which has PID of zero.

Answer (score 6):

[Kyle's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51124) is still valid as of today. In case you want to verify that, here is a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=0
for i in {1..100000}; do
  : &
  if [ $! -lt $pid ]; then
    echo "Min pid: $!"
    echo "Max pid: $pid"
    break
  fi
  pid=$!
done
```

This prints:

```
Min pid: 100
Max pid: 99998
```