# How to increase the max user processes hard limit(Mojave)

Tags: macos, launchd

How do I increase my max process hard limit. Currently, I can't go more than 2500. I'm on Mojave 10.14.6.

Currently what I do is:

```
sudo vim /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxproc.plist // and then increase the limit

sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxproc.plist 
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxproc.plist
launchctl limit
```

I can only increase it to 2500. I want it to be much higher than that.

Comment: Can I ask what you need a higher limit for?

Comment: @benwiggy. Sure, it's to run a wonderful experiment called Bashlog. https://github.com/thomasrebele/bashlog/issues/3.

Comment: @RAbraham - from comments on github there seems some confusion between *maxproc* (max number of concurrent processes) and *pid_max* (where process id number wraps).  *maxproc* is 2500 while *pid_max* is [99999](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51119/whats-the-maximum-pid-for-mac-os-x) on macOS.  On linux *pid_max* is 32768 for 32 bit systems or up to [4194304](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16883/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-the-process-id) for 64 bit.  Looks like (as you suggested) perhaps something isn't closing properly as you shouldn't need that many active processes.

Comment: @lx07. I'm extremely grateful that you took the time out to look at the Bashlog issue and provide such a valuable comment. I will relay that to the author. If you ever are ok with connecting on LinkedIn or something, let me know. I'm at https://www.linkedin.com/in/rajivabraham/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like kernel is hard coded to 2500 in [param.c](https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu/blob/master/bsd/conf/param.c)

```c
#if CONFIG_EMBEDDED
#define NPROC 1000          /* Account for TOTAL_CORPSES_ALLOWED by making this slightly lower than we can. */
#define NPROC_PER_UID 950
#else
#define NPROC (20 + 16 * 32)
#define NPROC_PER_UID (NPROC/2)
#endif

/* NOTE: maxproc and hard_maxproc values are subject to device specific scaling in bsd_scale_setup */
#define HNPROC 2500 /* based on thread_max */
int maxproc = NPROC;
int maxprocperuid = NPROC_PER_UID;

#if CONFIG_EMBEDDED
int hard_maxproc = NPROC;   /* hardcoded limit -- for embedded the number of processes is limited by the ASID space */
#else
int hard_maxproc = HNPROC;  /* hardcoded limit */
#endif
```

and while this *may* be scaled in [bcd_scale_setup](https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu/blob/master/bsd/dev/unix_startup.c) (if you are running [server version](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3854)), *hard_maxproc* is always taken as upper limit according to [syslimits.h](https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu/blob/master/bsd/sys/syslimits.h)

```c
#if !defined(_ANSI_SOURCE)
/*
 * Note: CHILD_MAX *must* be less than hard_maxproc, which is set at
 * compile time; you *cannot* set it higher than the hard limit!!
 */
#define ARG_MAX        (256 * 1024) /* max bytes for an exec function */
#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
#define CHILD_MAX          266  /* max simultaneous processes */
```