# unexpected `lsof -a` output

Tags: command-line, macos

My `lsof` command output is correct while the application I am tracking with `lsof -a` is running. As soon as I quit that application the same `lsof -a` call displays results for every process that has an ESTABLISHED connection.

`lsof -lnPO -i -sTCP:ESTABLISHED -a -p "$(pgrep -d, qbittorrent)" +c0`

Upon closing qbittorrent it then shows every connection that is "ESTABLISHED"

I want results for ESTABLISHED qbittorrent connections and when there are none, no connections.

I am displaying this output through GeekTool on the Desktop.
It runs as a shell script.

`nice -n 9 /Users/john/ShellScripts/GeekTool/qBT-Activity.sh`

Comment: I'd assume this has to do with `pgrep -d, qbittorrent` returning nothing, and `lsof` interpreting `-p ""` as meaning "all processes". The thing I don't understand is why it doesn't show everything *before* you start `qbittorrent` the first time.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I get all processes listed even without having run `qbittorrent` once. So either there are no ESTABLISHED connections the first time the OP runs the command (unlikely), or we miss part of the picutre.

Comment: @GordonDavisson @nohillside I apologize. I must be losing my marbles. After looking at it again, restarting the computer does nothing to change behavior. I don't know for sure what is different but I agree that `-p ""` seems to be interpreted as "all processes". It may be the difference between the `proctools` version of `pgrep` and the system installed version. I recently changed my `$PATH` to put the proctools version first because the native `pgrep` was having an issue with `-d ,` flag adding a ',' as a terminator a while back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `pgrep` doesn't find a match, it returns an empty string which apparently triggers `lsof` to return all established connections.

In Bash, try

```
lsof -lnPO -i -sTCP:ESTABLISHED -a \
    -p "$(p=$(pgrep -d, qbittorrent); echo ${p:-9999999999999999})" \
    +c0
```

instead (which substitutes an unlikely "pid" if no `qbittorrent` process is running).

Comment: Thanks @nohillside. I am not familiar with the notation `:-`. What is happening in that command substitution or parameter expansion? Max PID is [99998](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51119/whats-the-maximum-pid-for-mac-os-x) on macOS... so definitely unlikely.

Comment: @john if p is set and not empty, the value of p is used. Otherwise the value after :-  . See man bash for details.

Comment: `pgrep` (at least in the versions I know of) exits with error status if it doesn't find any matches, so `... -p "$(pgrep -d, qbittorrent || echo 9999999999999999)" ...` should also work.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Ahhhh, right, absolutely!

Answer (score 0):

@nohillside Thanks for your solution! I found a method by testing for exit status. I don't know which is more "efficient".

Now using `/usr/bin/pgrep` and not `/usr/local/bin/pgrep`

```sh
my_func() {
if /usr/bin/pgrep -q qbittorrent
then
  lsof -lnPO -a -i -sTCP:ESTABLISHED -a -p "$(/usr/bin/pgrep qbittorrent)" +c0
fi
}
```

The opposite (testing for 1 exit code)

```sh
my_func() {
if ! /usr/bin/pgrep -q qbittorrent
then
  return
else
  lsof -lnPO -a -i -sTCP:ESTABLISHED -a -p "$(/usr/bin/pgrep qbittorrent)" +c0
fi
}
```

`-q` flag suppresses stdout, but only in macOS installed `pgrep` and unfortunately not the proctools version of `pgrep`

Comment: This works as well, but there is a race condition if the BitTorrent process ends after the if and before the lsof (unlikely but possible). It also runs pgrep twice.